# Boost::asio и параллелизм в многопоточности

Tags: c++, многопоточность, asio

У меня есть задача, которая заключается в том, чтобы вызвать метод, который является запросом на удалённый сервер; после этого я хочу, чтобы ожидался ответ, причём ожидание не блокирует другие ассинхронные методы/объекты (например: таймеры).

Имеется метод got_response(...), который сообщает ожидающим, что случился ответ от удалённого сервера, так же метод получает на вход данные, которые мы получили в ответ.
Ниже описано моё решение этой задачи, но иногда asio может вызвать таймеры в одном потоке, тем самым ожидание ответа заблокирует вызов самого ответа (got_response).

Как я могу вызвать таймер с ожиданием ответа (timer2) гарантированно в другом потоке с таймером для симуляции ответа (timer3)? Или есть какая-нибудь другая реализация подобной задачи?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

namespace io = boost::asio;

struct Reply
{
    atomic<bool> ready;
    atomic<int> result;

    future<void> future_result;

    Reply()
    {
        ready = false;
        result = 0;
    }

    void call()
    {
        cout << "retry called!" << endl;
        future_result = async([&]()
                              {
                                  while (!ready)
                                  {
                                      this_thread::yield();
                                  }
                              });
    }

    int get()
    {
        future_result.wait();
        return result.load();
    }

    void got_response(int res)
    {
        result = res;
        ready = true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Reply reply;
    reply.call();

    io::io_context context(4);

    io::steady_timer timer1(context, std::chrono::seconds(2));
    timer1.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
                      { cout << "timer 1, thread name: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl; });

    io::steady_timer timer2(context, std::chrono::seconds(3));
    timer2.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
                      {
                          cout << "timer 2, thread name: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
                          cout << reply.get() << endl;
                      });

    io::steady_timer timer3(context, std::chrono::seconds(10));
    timer3.async_wait([&](const boost::system::error_code &ec)
                      {
                          cout << "timer 3, thread name: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
                          reply.got_response(1337);
                      });

    vector<thread> threads;
    auto count = 2;

    for (int n = 0; n < count; ++n)
    {
        threads.emplace_back([&]
                             { context.run(); });
    }

    for (auto &th : threads)
    {
        th.join();
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
retry called!
timer 1, thread name: 140712511198784
timer 2, thread name: 140712519591488
timer 3, thread name: 140712511198784
1337
```

Comment: Избавьтесь от дополнительных потоков и от всех `::std::async`

Comment: @user7860670 тогда ожидание ответа в timer2 будет блокировать весь поток и другие таймеры не будут работать.

Comment: Такого быть не должно, т.е. никаких wait или бесконечных циклов. Все асинхронные задачи должны раздаваться строго посредством контекста boost.

Comment: @user7860670 в любом случае, в asio я не могу реализовать ожидание результата в одном потоке. Той же await или yield попросту нет.

Comment: Ожидание результат в примере происходит при добавлении обработчика `timer3.async_wait` вот в нем этот результат и надо обрабатывать, а никакие дополнительные ожидания при этом не нужны.

Comment: @user7860670 таймер является не ожиданием результата, а ожиданием времени. А если я буду ожидать результат внутри callback'a таймера, то это ожидание заблокирует вызовы других callback'ов у других таймеров.

Comment: Тут нигде нет необходимости внутри обработчиков что-то ждать. Если после выполнения одного обработчика необходимо что-то сделать в другом, то все эти действия следует перенести в другой обработчик.